# NLP - What to do when unigram is not present in corpus while doing stupid backoff smoothing

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, smoothing, language-model

In stupid backoff for smoothing for trigrams, if trigram is not found then we backoff to bigram , if bigram is also not found we backoff to unigram. But what if unigram is not present in the corpus. In the [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D07-1090.pdf) under stupid backoff section it is mentioned that

> The
>   recursion ends at unigrams

So what probability should be assigned to a completely new unigram, which is not present in training dataset.

Comment: A typical solution: Just set a threshold K (i.e. K=5) and pre-process your training corpus. Then replace all words occurring less that K-times in the corpus with a generic term UNK. During test phase, replace the unknown word with the UNK.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to assign to zerograms a  probability of 1/V where V is the size of your vocabulary. Or, alternatively, replace rare words in you corpus by a keyword (for instance: UNK) and calculate corresponding probabilities in your initial corpus.